# PC Rebooting randomly. PSU failure or not?

Tags: power-supply, reboot

Sometimes when I play heavy games my computer reboots/turns off without prompting, blue screens, ...
It just shuts down after 5 minutes of gaming, but it happens only with specific games (ONLY Star Citizen Beta and Far Cry 3).

I looked on internet for solutions:
Someone reccomends to "Update your DirectX" and to update other drivers/libraries/...
Nothing worked. Then I thought that it can be the PSU, but I'm not sure. Why it happens only with games created with the CryEngine?
So I'm not sure. The PSU should provide sufficient power. It's a good class PSU and it provides 200W more than required.
Then I opened the bios and I looked for the voltages.

3.3V -> 3.280, lower
5V -> 5.080, not too high
12V -> 12.198, **0.2V higher?????**

I don't think that the voltage is too low, but that 12.198 is very strange. It isn't obviously causing a power loss, but maybe it can create other problems? IDK.
Any idea? Other solutions? Anyways, thank you.

CPU: i7-4770K 
GPU: Gigabyte GTX 770OC
PSU: FSP Aurum Series AU-600
RAM: 16GB DDR3 1600MHz

Comment: Which PSU is it and what is the rest of your hardware components? Mainly CPU and GPU. Have you checked if the GPU is overheating and thus shutting down to avoid further damage?

Comment: Edited. I'll re-check the system power consumption...

Comment: And I'm sure that the GPU and CPU aren't overheating.

Comment: You're not checking the voltages when under load, so the figures are pretty meaningless. How old is the PSU? They get 'tired' with age. Gigabyte's spec says minimum 600w PSU which might get marginal with age. That PSU can push 18A on each 12v rail, so be sure you're using 2 rails for the extra power cables on the GPU

Comment: I had the same problem, with the same game, with the amount of RAM. I had 2 x 8GB sticks, as a test I removed one of the 8GB sticks and never had the problem again...

Comment: OK I'll try but please add an answer so I can select the correct one if it works. I'm already using 2 connectors on the GPU, so I'll try to remove a ram slot, play the game, and then if it works I'll test the ram, else remove another slot and retry, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, with the same game, with the amount of RAM. I had 2 x 8GB sticks, as a test I removed one of the 8GB sticks and never had the problem again.

Quick and easy to test, give it a try.

Comment: THANKS A LOT! I removed the third slot from left and now it doesn't crash! Now I'll figure out if the RAM is damaged or there is a way to use it anyways... CryEngine lol.

Comment: No problem, that's good news. :)